# modify session with twig

Tags: session, twig

It is possible to access session in twig that way :

```
{{app.session.get('full_screen')}}
```

and I can retrieve my 'full_screen' attribute

Question : Is it possible to modify this attribute in session ? How to set a 'done' value to this attribute ?

Thanks to you

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but why would you want to modify the session from the view layer?

Comment: why not ? can you tell me how to do it with Twig ?

Comment: Because it violates the layer separation principle. If you really want to do it, though, try `app.session.set(key, value)`.